# @transactional annotation of Spring JPA don't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I've a problem with transactions. I use Spring Jpa(1.8.2), Hibernate(4.3), MariaDB, Jboss EAP 6.2.
I expect that the method saveExample() in the service class dosen't write nothing on the table because the method thows an exception and does rollback.

This is my code:
persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="fooPU">
    .........
        <class>ExampleCass</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Service.java

```
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Service
@Transactional
public class ExampleService {
    private TableExampleRepository exampleRepo;
    private JpaTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleService(TableExampleRepository exampleRepo) {
        this.exampleRepo = exampleRepo;
    }



    @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class})
    public void saveExample(ExampleClass example ){

        exampleRepo.save(example);
        throw new RuntimeException("foo");

    }


}
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.7.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder
        location="file:///${jboss.modules.dir}/system/layers/base/...../foo.properties" />

     <jpa:repositories base-package="it.foo.repository"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
        transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/> 

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" name="foo"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" /> 
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="fooPU" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >             
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
             </bean>    

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- Data Source -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/fooDS"
        id="datasource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />




    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="message" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="foo" />

</beans>
```

Controller.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("att1")
public class ExampleController extends ReportController {
    private ExampleService exampleService;

    @Autowired
    public ExampleController(ExampleService exampleService) {
        this.exampleService = exampleService;
    }
    .......
    @RequestMapping(value = "/salvaExample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String visualizzaProspetto(@RequestParam ExampleClass example,Model model) {
        exampleService.saveExample( example); 
        return "page1";
    }
    .......
}
```

**EDIT 1** this is my servlet-context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="foo" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/WEB-INF/resources/webjars/" />

</beans:beans>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: How do you call saveExample()?

Comment: From a Spring controller (@Controller)

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: If you're running inside JBoss, using a DataSource defined in JBoss, you should use a JtaTransactionManager.

Comment: Is your save() method in TableExampleRepository also @Transactional?

Comment: Try removing the Transactional definition from the class, or add the rollbackFor property to the class level annotation instead of the method level annotation.

Comment: In effect I use a Datasource definde in Jboss, I tried with JtaTransactionManager and the transactional method worked fine.

Comment: Let me guess you also have a `*-servlet.xml` which also has a `<context:component-scan />`...

Comment: @M.Deinum I posted an edit at end of my original post. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you are scanning for everything twice. Leading to an instance in the root context (which has proper transactions applied using AOP) and an instance in the servlet context (without transactions applied) the last one is used. Your root context should scan for everything BUT `@Controller`s and the servlet context should only scan for `@Controller`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your configuration files contain the following line:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo" />
```

This line does exactly what it is told to do it will scan for components and it will do it for both the `ContextLoaderListener` and the `DispatcherServlet`. This results in 2 bean instances. The one picked up by the `ContextLoaderListener` will have proper transactions applied because in that same context is a `<tx:annotation-driven />` however that isn't the case for the instance in the `DispatcherServlet.

Your controllers will use the bean instance registered in the closest application context, the one loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` so without transactions.

In short when doing component scanning you should take care of not scanning the same components twice. If you have a very broad `base-package` to scan you can use include and exclude filters.

In your `root-context.xml` use the following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

In your `servlet-context.xml` use the following.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```